# Displaying heatmap with large number of dense points of interest in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, cartography, heat-map, density

I am currently trying to make heatmaps of bird observations in an area. I have had a lot of success making the actual heatmaps for most birds, except the ones that are extremely abundant. I use the heatmaps to find density of the birds per acre at a given point, so it's important for me to get all of the birds on a map. I was wondering if anyone has had experience with making heatmaps from numerous, dense points? What do you need to do differently to get it to show up?

Comment: Please clarify "numerous": how many points are you dealing with? Also, how do you create the heatmap (since there are multiple possibilities)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the heatmap option from the layer property.

[image]
Just double click on the layers' name then on the dialog box select 
Style--->Heatmap

[image]

This is my result:

[image]